# Reproduce scrollIntoView with something similar function pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I use scrollIntoView if my current item does not appear in the parent's perspective.
If my item has a 'offsetTop' greater than the parent offsetHeight, go through the item slightly to appear in the parent view.

I have a bug when I use `scrollIntoView` on safari. Partially supported by many browsers only in chrome and mozilla works https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Another problem when used in both `smooth` places seems to be an animation with interruptions.

My try:

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
     const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-elementid='${action.payload.id}']`);

     elements.forEach((element) => {
         const menuContainer = element.parentElement.parentElement.offsetHeight;
         const elementsHeight = element.offsetTop;

         if (elementsHeight > menuContainer) {
             element.scrollIntoView({
                 behavior: 'smooth',
                 block: 'end',
             });
         }
     });
};

setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 200);
```

I use this feature in two places per page.
How can I replace the scrollIntoView function with something else to do the same.

Comment: You can use anchors links and css transitions.